# SMS service providing a custom sender ID

Tags: sms

Is there any service like Textlocal or Nexmo or just a simple SMS gateway allowing using a custom ID for sending messages to the US networks?

I don’t need any API or so and a limit of 10 messages per day would be more than enough.

*Custom sender ID*:

> This is the name or number which flashes on the recipient's mobile phone when they receive an SMS Text message. Most GSM Networks/Operators accept up to an 8-character Alpha-Numeric String as Sender Identification.